# How to Create Accuracy Quality Checks with a Reference Table

Tags: sql, geolocation, left-join, snowflake-schema

I have two tables in snowflake - a table with records filled in from customers, and a reference table with State, Region and Sub-Region fields.  The reference table is accurate in that if State is 'California', Region and Sub-Region are West and Pacific, respectively.

I'm trying to create a quality check to confirm the data in my records table is also accurate.  The snowflake sql query should produce results when records are not reflecting the accurate combination of state/region/subregion.  For example, if a customer record contained 'California', 'East', 'Pacific', I would want this record to show up in the query results.

I've tried to join these two tables but am struggling with the sql syntax.  Have reviewed different case statement combinations as well, but no success thus far.

Reference Table

| State | Region | Subregion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| California | West | Pacific |
| Alabama | South | Southeast |
| Maine | East | Northeast |

Customer Records table

| ID | State | Region | Subregion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3469 | California | East | Pacific |
| 4874 | Alabama | South | Southeast |
| 5890 | Maine | East | North |

Would like Query results to show:

| ID | State | Region | Subregion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3469 | California | East | Pacific |
| 5890 | Maine | East | North |

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. As it stands, there is more than one way to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach to perform the quality checks ( these worked with my use cases )

Assuming that you already have a `Reference table`, if not create one initially,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reference_table (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  expected_value VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Then
join the `reference table` to the data table to compare the expected values to the actual values

```
SELECT data_table.id, 
      data_table.value, 
      reference_table.expected_value
FROM data_table
INNER JOIN reference_table ON data_table.id = reference_table.id;
```

you can Use a WHERE clause to filter out any records where the actual value doesn't match the expected value

```
SELECT data_table.id, 
        data_table.value, 
        reference_table.expected_value
FROM data_table
INNER JOIN reference_table ON data_table.id = reference_table.id
WHERE data_table.value = reference_table.expected_value;
```

Finally, you could calculate the accuracy metrics like below ( Note that this depends on the checks that you want to make w.r.t to the columns in the tables, am just giving you possible aggregations.) on those filtered records ( using WHERE)

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS total_count, 
  SUM(CASE 
          WHEN data_table.value = reference_table.expected_value 
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS accurate_count,
  AVG(CASE 
         WHEN data_table.value = reference_table.expected_value 
      THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) AS accuracy_percentage
FROM data_table
INNER JOIN reference_table ON data_table.id = reference_table.id;
```

The above query will give you the total count of records, the count of accurate records, and the percentage of accurate records out of the total. You can adjust the logic to fit your specific use case and data needs.

Let me know your feedback, if this helped your use case.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want `not exists`.

To show all customers whose state/region/subregion is invalid (ie does not exist in the reference table):

```
select c.*
from customer c
where not exists (
    select 1
    from reference r
    where r.state = c.state and r.region = c.region and r.subregion = c.subregion
)
```

We could also specifically look for customers whose state exists but whose region/subregion is invalid:

```
select c.*
from customer c
where not exists (
    select 1
    from reference r
    where r.state = c.state and r.region = c.region and r.subregion = c.subregion
) and exists (
    select 1
    from reference r
    where r.state = c.state
)
```